# The pubspec.lock file has changed since the .dart_tool/package_config.json file was generated, please run "pub get" again

Tags: flutter, codemagic, build-runner

I try to run test on codemagic with custom pre-test script. And this is my pre-test script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd libraries
cd dependencies
flutter pub get
cd ..
cd core
flutter pub get
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
cd ..
cd ..
cd features
cd splash
flutter pub get
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
cd ..
cd proposal
flutter pub get
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

And this I my flutter project structure:
[image]

But when the `pre-test` is running, I get this error:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in dependencies...                        2.5s
Running "flutter pub get" in core...                                4.9s
The pubspec.lock file has changed since the .dart_tool/package_config.json file was generated, please run "pub get" again.
pub finished with exit code 65
Running "flutter pub get" in splash...                              3.0s
The pubspec.lock file has changed since the .dart_tool/package_config.json file was generated, please run "pub get" again.
pub finished with exit code 65
Running "flutter pub get" in proposal...                            3.2s
The pubspec.lock file has changed since the .dart_tool/package_config.json file was generated, please run "pub get" again.
pub finished with exit code 65


Build failed :|
Step 4 script `Pre-test script` exited with status code 65
```

I think this error is because of `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` when I want generated `.g.dart` file via codemagic.

I try to google but still not found a solution, can someone help me how to solve this error on codemagic?

Comment: not related to your question but you can use one-liner for cd commands `cd libraries/dependencies` and `cd ../core` to keep script cleaner

Comment: I found this error was opaque, and the actual issue was it having trouble running `build_runner` with a package in `pubspec.yaml` using the `path` parameter. Once I switched that to a git repo pointer, `build_runner` worked properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fix with add `flutter pub run` twice.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd libraries
cd dependencies
flutter pub get
cd ..
cd core
flutter pub get
flutter pub get // add again
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
cd ..
cd ..
cd features
cd splash
flutter pub get
flutter pub get // add again
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
cd ..
cd proposal
flutter pub get
flutter pub get // add again
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```